# IndexError: list index out of range csv reader python

Tags: python, csv

I have the following csv called `report.csv`.  It's an excel file:

```
email   agent_id    misc
test@email.com  65483843154f35d54   blah1
test1@email.com sldd989eu99ufj9ej9e blah 2
```

I have the following code:

```
import csv

data_file =  'report.csv'
def import_data(data_file):
    attendee_data = csv.reader(open(data_file, 'rU'), dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    for row in attendee_data:
        email = row[1]
        agent_id = row[2]
        pdf_file_name = agent_id + '_' + email + '.pdf'
        generate_certificate(email, agent_id, pdf_file_name)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "report_test.py", line 56, in <module>
import_data(data_file)
File "report_test.py", line 25, in import_data
email = row[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I thought the index was the number of columns in, within each row.  `row[1]` and 'row[2]` should be within range, no?

Comment: You need to fix your indentation. Also, list indices start at 0.

Comment: @LukeP Sorry about the indentation.  I understand the indices start at 0.  So if there are 3 items, shouldn't 1 and 2 be in range?

Comment: The email column is row[0], your agent id is row[1] and your misc is row[2], It looks like you just need to shift the indexes.

Comment: Yes, I commented because 1 and 2 should be in range, but won't represent email and agent_id. I have never used the csv module. It looks like you are specifying tab delimited with that dialect, are you sure that your file is tab delimited?

Comment: @LukeP not sure that it's tab delimited.  It's an excel csv.  What else could I use?

Comment: I had this issue at one point when my CSV ended in a blank line; it was trying to break the blank line into individual fields.  I solved it by wrapping the variable assignments in: `try: email, agent_id = row[:2] / except IndexError: pass / else: # everything else...`.

Comment: What does print row tells you?

Answer (score 2):

There is most likely a blank line in your CSV file. Also, list indices start at 0, not 1.

```
import csv

data_file =  'report.csv'
def import_data(data_file):
    attendee_data = csv.reader(open(data_file, 'rU'), dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    for row in attendee_data:
        try:
            email = row[0]
            agent_id = row[1]
        except IndexError:
            pass
        else:
            pdf_file_name = agent_id + '_' + email + '.pdf'
            generate_certificate(email, agent_id, pdf_file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you have an "Excel CSV", which I don't quite understand so I'll answer assuming you have an actual `.csv` file.

If I'm loading a `.csv` into memory (and the file isn't enormous), I'll often have a `load_file` method on my class that doesn't care about indexes.

Assuming the file has a header row:

```
import csv

def load_file(filename):

    # Define data in case the file is empty.
    data = []
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        headers = next(reader)
        data = [dict(zip(headers, row)) for row in reader]

    return data
```

This returns a list of dictionaries you can use by key, instead of index. The key will be absent in the event, say `misc` is missing from the row (index 2), so simply `.get` from the `row`. This is cleaner than a `try...except`.

```
for row in data:
    email = row.get('email')
    agent_id = row.get('agent_id')
    misc = row.get('misc')
```

This way the order of the file columns don't matter, only the headers do. Also, if any of the columns have a blank value, your script won't error out by giving an `IndexError`. If you don't want to include blank values, simply handle them by checking:

```
if not email:
    do.something()
if not agent_id:
    do.something_else()
```